# Highlight(change color) roads, footpaths or cycle paths in mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can we highlight(change color) roads, footpaths or cycle paths in mapbox gl js using toggle button?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [setPaintProperty](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty) to change a layer's fill color like it is done in this official Mapbox example (for a layer with `"type": "fill"`):

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/color-switcher/

For a layer with `"type": "line"` this PaintProperty would be `line-color`:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#paint-line-line-color

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    ...
});

button.onclick = function (e) {
    map.setPaintProperty(layer, prepertyName, value);
};
```